# How to compile-time check objects being passed to an NSArray constructor for nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, clang, clang-static-analyzer

`NSArray` rather dislikes being passed a `nil` object as part of its constructor:

```
UIView *aView;
UIView *aSecondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
NSArray *array = @[aView, aSecondView];
```

will throw an exception at runtime when `array` is created.

Does `clang` have any facilities to try and detect this kind of error? For some trivial cases (like the one above: a stack-local variable that's never assigned to), it seems like the sort of problem the static analyzer would hit out of the park.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `-Wuninitialized` catches that specific example, `__attribute__((nonnull))` for parameters to functions/methods would help catch `nil` as argument in general.

For this specific example (variable not specifically initialized), you can use `-Wuninitialized` to catch those uses:

```
○ xcrun clang a.m -F/System/Library/Frameworks -c -o a.o -Wuninitialized
a.m:6:22: warning: variable 'aView' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  NSArray *array = @[aView, aSecondView];
                     ^~~~~
a.m:4:16: note: initialize the variable 'aView' to silence this warning
  NSView *aView;// = nil;
               ^
                = nil
1 warning generated.
```

For passing `nullptr`/`NULL`/`nil` to functions/methods, `__attribute__((nonnull))` should work for most cases. Since this is an API provided by Apple, you would need to file a radar and hope they add it.

**P.S**: Actually, `__attribute__((nonnull))` wouldn't “simply work”, in this case (if you initialized `aView` to `nil`, for example. The `@[...]` sequence seems to be creating an array, and calling `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects: count:]`, where you would be able to mark the first argument as `nonnull`, but not the things pointed to by it. In any case, it should be relatively simple to write a clang pass for the analysis you mention. You should file a radar, since such a pass could avoid lots of time losses.

**P.P.S**: It seems `__attribute__((nonnull))` doesn't propagate much information, which is sad. :-( If you have a function `f(type arg __attribute__((nonnull)))` and you pass it a variable which you initialized to `nil` and never touched again, it doesn't warn.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are right, Clang static analyzer hit this error out of the park. It is built into Xcode (6 Beta as I tested on). Go **Building Settings** > Static Analyzer - Analysis Policy > Set **Analyze During 'Build'** to **Yes**. To manually perform, go Product > Analyze.

[image]

Static analyzer can also be used as [stand alone tool](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html) in command line. Other option to analyze at compile time is to add Run Script in Build Phases before Compile Sources.

Comment: I hadn't thought to try the Xcode 6 beta, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I'll check again, but last I looked, the analyzer in Xcode 5 didn't catch this case.